# How to change a value in C# ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to change/set one of the values in the `ConcurrentQueue`. `FixedSizedQueue` is a `ConcurrentQueue`.    I think the main issue I'm having to trying to get the ONE of the entries in this `ConcurrentQueue`. Any suggestions...

```
private void CalculateABC(FixedSizedQueue<Bar> q)
{
    decimal sum = 0.0m;

    foreach (var item in q.Queue)
    {
        sum = sum + item.close;
    }

        decimal ABCvalue = decimal.Round(sum / q.Limit, 5);

        //I'm trying to set the value HERE.  
        //((Bar)(q.Queue)Items[19]).ABC = ABCvalue;

    }
```

Comment: That's a design problem on your part. A queue is so named so that you don't have random access.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're trying to do and why you think you need a queue. The code you've shown doesn't need a queue. Can you explain the entire problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CalculateABC(FixedSizedQueue<Bar> q)
{
  decimal sum = 0.0m;

  Bar item19 = null;
  int index = 0;
  foreach (var item in q.Queue)
  { 
    if (index++ == 19)
      item19 = item;
    sum = sum + item.close;
  }

  decimal ABCvalue = decimal.Round(sum / q.Limit, 5);

  //I'm trying to set the value HERE.  
  if (item19 != null)
    item19.ABC = ABCvalue;
}
```

Comment: oops, forgot ++

Comment: You probably should have `++index`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - OP can decide

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just need to do this:

```
private void CalculateABC(FixedSizedQueue<Bar> q)
{
    q.Queue.Skip(19).First().ABC =
        decimal.Round(q.Queue.Sum(x => x.close) / q.Limit, 5);
}
```

Obviously you must ensure that your queue has at least 20 elements for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

While you may want to reevaluate using a queue instead of a list (or in this case a ConcurrentQueue instead of a ConcurrentBag) because it won't provide random access (and you'll need to enumerate all previous elements to get to the one you want) it still is an IEnumerable so you can use LINQ to index it, but the performance will be poor as indexing the 1000th element doesn't require going to adress of first element + 1000 but going over each of the previous 999 elements.

In any case the simplest solution if you want to stick with a queue and index it is to replace your example of

```
queue[19]
```

with

```
queue.ElementAt(19)
```

So the full example would be :

```
private void CalculateABC(FixedSizedQueue<Bar> q)
{
   // Replace your summing of each item's close property with a simple LINQ sum
   decimal sum = q.Queue.Sum(item=>item.close);

   decimal ABCvalue = decimal.Round(sum / q.Limit, 5);

   // No need for any casting, you're already working on generics, it's already a Bar, don't cast a Bar to a Bar
   q.Queue.ElementAt(19).ABC = ABCvalue;
}
```